# How to test a Jersey endpoint without additional frameworks

Tags: java, junit, jersey

I am developing jersey endpoints and I have to do the integration test for this endpoints, my doubt is how can I make the unit test for this endpoint without adding more dependencies to the pom or additional libraries, because it is a restriction. There is a way to achieve that? I am using junit version 5. This is an example of my endpoint. I was using jerseyTest but I had to revert my changes, because of the restriction:

```
@GET
@Path("/")
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = SC_OK, response = HorasPaginatedResult.class,
                message = "Successfully retrievedHoras from Labor Service"),
        @ApiResponse(code = SC_BAD_REQUEST, response = ErrorMessage.class, message = "The request was malformed or missing a required field"),
        @ApiResponse(code = SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, response = ErrorMessage.class, message = "There was an issue processing the request and the server has failed out of the action"),
})
@ApiOperation(value = "Used to query the time service for timeclocks.",
        response = HorasPaginatedResult.class,
        tags = "Horas",
        nickname = "get-Horas.all")
public PaginatedResult<Horas> getHorasAll(
        @Nullable @ApiParam("the token to the next page of results") @QueryParam("token") String token,
        @Nullable @ApiParam(value = "the field to sort by - this may through a 500 error if the index does not exsist", example = "timestamp") @QueryParam("sortBy") String sortBy,
        @Nullable @ApiParam("boolean to determine which direction the sort should be in") @QueryParam("sortAscending") Boolean sortAscending,
        @Nullable @ApiParam("the maximum number of 'records' to return per page") @QueryParam("recordLimit") Integer recordLimit,
        @Nullable @ApiParam(value = "object", example = "%7B%22field%22%") @QueryParam("expression") List<Query.Expression> expressions) {
    Query query;
    if (token != null) {
        query = new Query(token);
    } else {
        query = new Query(sortBy, recordLimit, sortAscending);
        if (expressions != null) {
            expressions.forEach(query.getExpressions()::add);
        }
    }
    logger.info("creating query of {}", query);
    return HorasService.getHoras(query);
}


private static class HorasPaginatedResult extends PaginatedResult<BanquetLaborHoras> {

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Jersey provides an effective testing coverage, but you need to add at least one jersey testing framework dependency to the pom.

Comment: You will not be able to run integration tests without adding any extra dependencies. You will only be able to run _unit_ tests, in which case, you will do a lot of mocking.

Comment: Also `HorasService.getHoras()`... stuff like this is not good for unit tests. You should use dependency injection so you can provide dependencies for the tests.